# Android Studio not generating data store indexes for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-datastore

Whenever I run my appengine project on local host and run queries the **datastore-indexes-auto.xml** file does not generate the indexes. I've tried adding `autoGenerate="True"` but it didn't change a thing.

Whenever I run the project the file gets updates but always displays the same text:

```
<!-- Indices written at Wed, 27 Jan 2016 21:08:31 CAT -->

<datastore-indexes/>
```

I've searched for a fix to this issue but couldn't find anyone with the same problem.

This happens for all app engine modules I have on Android Studio.

I'm using *Android Studio 1.2.2*  and the libraries I'm using are:

- *App Engine SDK 1.9.21*;
- *Objectify 5.0*.

Comment: assuming that's the entire content of your `datastore-indexes-auto.xml` file it seems incorrect syntactically - missing the opening `<datastore-index>` tag. I would simply remove it and re-try - it should get re-generated automatically from scratch.

Comment: Already tried that @DanCornilescu, the file always revert to that state when I run on localhost. That's the whole text really, tried modifying the tags, tried adding the autoGenerate="True" statement between the tags but still nothing.

Comment: the only other thought I have is the `autoGenerate="true"` attribute in the `WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml` file: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig#Java_Using_automatic_index_configuration

Comment: @DanCornilescu thanks, that helped, you should rewrite your comment as and answer, I don't have enough points to up vote yet but I can mark your answer as accepted. I did not have the *datastore-indexes.xml* file on my project, added the file and the autoGenerate tag and it worked. I was always adding that tag on the appengine generated xml file, that's probably why it didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the comment an answer.

You need to set the `autoGenerate="true"` attribute in the `WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml` file:

From [Using automatic index configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig#Java_Using_automatic_index_configuration):

> Determining the indexes required by your application's queries
>   manually can be tedious and error-prone. Thankfully, the development
>   server can determine the index configuration for you. To use automatic
>   index configuration, add the attribute autoGenerate="true" to your
>   WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml file's `<datastore-indexes>` element.
>   Automatic index configuration is also used if your app does not have a
>   datastore-indexes.xml file.